# How can you load an Android Layout file in Java code as opposed to placing it statically in the main xml layout file?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have the layout file below (picture_section_fragment.xml) and would like to load it in Java code rather than placing it statically in the main xml layout file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/pic_sec_frag_id">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="520dp"
    android:id="@+id/My_Container_1_ID"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I am pretty sure the error (bottom of the question) is happening in the code block below at the mPager line. The reason I don't want to place the picture_segment_fragment.xml file in the main activity layout file statically is because I am loading images via a URL during runtime (in a separate java file I have not placed here). Any help on how to load the picture_segment_fragment.xml file in java code would be greatly appreciated! **BTW** I am not placing the ViewPager in the main xml layout file because I do not want the whole page to be swipe able. I only want a part of the page to be swipe able.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// For this example, only two pages
static final int NUM_ITEMS = 3;
ViewPager mPager;
SlidePagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getDirectionsButton);
    clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Get Directions Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    /* Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter. */
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new SlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
} ............................
```

**ERROR :**

> 12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.newmoney.night_life_now/com.newmoney.night_life_now.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.newmoney.night_life_now.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
>   12-07 23:31:31.729 23227-23227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

Answer (score 0):

If this is the layout for your fragment, it should be inflated and returned from [`onCreateView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)).

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.picture_segment_fragment, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I caught you wrong :)

**Your Pager** is in

> `picture_section_fragment.xml`

file and **you are using** in acitivity is

> `activity_main`

so you **don't have** that

> pager id in your `activity_main`

So you have to **use** either

> `picture_section_fragment.xml` or you have to add your pager into
>   `activity_main`.xml file

Comment: Thanks! But I guess this brings me to my next issue. How do I place the picture_section _fragment.xml In a specific part of the main xml file without placing it statically in the main xml file. Such as, should I load this through java code in the Main Activity class?